# Python PIL Image Module ImportError: No module named PIL, No module named Image

Tags: python, shell, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I've installed Python 2.7 alongside Python 2.4 as instructed [here](http://blog.hackedexistence.com/mediatemple-centos-5-5-ve-server-build-django-1-3-python-2-7-mysql-5-5-php-5-3).  When running a tests through **Mac OSX Terminal connecting to the Server** to confirm that the install is working I execute this test:

```
import Image
img = Image.open("/directory/image.jpg")
img.load()
print img
```

Result:

```
<PixelAccess object at 0x2b97d4c25110>
<JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=75x75 at 0xFEF4050>
```

However, when executing this using PHP's `exec()` or through a Coda extension [Run Script](http://joebergantine.com/werkstatt/run-script) for Coda, I get the error:

```
ImportError: No module named Image
```

I've also tried `from PIL import Image` which does not make a difference. Something else to note is that when I check to make sure that the support is there I get this which indicates that the proper image support is available:

```
*** TKINTER support not available
--- JPEG support available
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
--- FREETYPE2 support available
*** LITTLECMS support not available
```

**Question:** Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: total longshot, but why don't you try uninstalling PIL and installing [PILLOW](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.2.1)? Then you can actually do `import PIL.Image` etc. instead of the silly `import Image` thing that PIL makes you do. I doubt it will fix the import problem, but it wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@stwhite I suggest you to use virtualenv (http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html) for multiple projects to live in their own environments.

Usefull wrapper for virtualenv http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/

My own projects live in their own virtualenvs and its really awesome.

Here is the question about creating virtualenv with specific python version [Use different Python version with virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv)

**Note**
May be you'll have problems when installing PIL into the virtualenv

**Solution**

```
First install XCode with gcc support,
deactivate <virtualenv_name>
cd ../ (virtualenvs root)
pip install -E <virtualenv_name/> PIL
```

Hope this will work for you too,

Thanks,

Sultan

Comment: Though this could be an option to starting over, I'm hoping there is a solution to fix the current issue without redoing the whole setup.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is running the wrong version of Python. Specify the full path to the `python` executable.

Comment: I thought that might be the problem, however I ran `import sys` then `print sys.version_info` which returns 2.7.1: `sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=1, releaselevel='final', serial=0)`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your PYTHONPATH is correct when running via exec() call.

```
Import sys
print sys.path
sys.path.append ("<path of Image>")
```

You can also load the module dynamically, at runtime to ensure its available, provided its available in the standard location.